# storeAs/triggeredBy for an InputTask

Tags: sbt

I know how to use storeAs/triggeredBy for a task, like in

`discoveredDist <<= (dist in Bundle).storeAs(discoveredDist in Global).triggeredBy(dist in Bundle)`

How can I do the same for an InputTask?

Answer (score 1):

You can call `toTask(" arg")`. Here's an example:

```
lazy val definedFooNames = taskKey[Seq[String]]("")
lazy val fooInputTask = inputKey[Seq[String]]("")
fooInputTask := {
  val args: Seq[String] = Def.spaceDelimited("<arg>").parsed
  args
}
definedFooNames <<= fooInputTask.toTask(" 1 2 3") storeAs definedFooNames
```

This will work only for the hardcoded arguments. If you need to grab the result from input task with user input, you probably have to capture the result somewhere else.